# Setting up Google Analytics (gtag) to track ad blocking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, adblock, gtag.js

I've followed an online article as closely as possible (along with reading up in other articles) to track ad blocking but Google seems to have changed their GA tag lately to a new version called GTAG (no longer the same old "universal" tag.

https://www.kaushik.net/avinash/adblock-tracking-google-analytics-code-metrics-reports

I haven't found enough online documentation on how to set this up properly along with setting up the segment in GA to track adblock: true or false. So far, I just get a chart that tracks the adblocking event.

I am a GA GTM newbie and I've always found their UI horrible to navigate but that's besides the point. I hope someone can help with some tips if I've set up incorrectly. Thanks!

Here's what I have in GTM as a new tag as I didn't think I could use the standard GA tag where you just enter your id (I'd have to put the extra code I needed somewhere else and it would get messy imo):

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-ID">
</script>
<script>
  var isAdBlockEnabled;

  (function AdBlockEnabled() {
    var ad = document.createElement('ins');
    ad.className = 'AdSense';
    ad.style.display = 'block';
    ad.style.position = 'absolute';
    ad.style.top = '-1px';
    ad.style.height = '1px';
    document.body.appendChild(ad);
    isAdBlockEnabled = !ad.clientHeight;
    document.body.removeChild(ad);
    return isAdBlockEnabled;
  })()

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  // Configures custom dimension<Index> to use the custom parameter
  // 'dimension_name' for 'GA_TRACKING_ID', where <Index> is a number
  // representing the index of the custom dimension.
  gtag('config', 'UA-ID', {
    'custom_map': {'1': 'AdsBlocked'}
  });

  // Sends the custom dimension to Google Analytics.
  gtag('event', 'adsBlocked', {'AdsBlocked': isAdBlockEnabled});
</script>
```

Also, here's my GA segment setup - let me know if you guys need to see anything more:

[image]

I'm not sure when Google changed their tag but the old one seemed a lot more straightforward to set up. Thanks for the advice !

Comment: Universal Analytics is still valid. gtag is Google's new tracking library which eventually will work for all platforms (AdWords, Analytics etc...). My experience with gtag over the last few months: it's still very early, not greatly documented, things are changing... My advise would be to stick to Universal Analytics for now.

Comment: Thanks @Max, I guess I will switch back for now. I'm lucky I have used GA before so I have the old code but even google is taking references to their old tag out so I hope there's some better documentation out there soon. Appreciate the time!

Comment: Just an update, something in the GA side must have changed. I set it up with the old tag the way the article suggested but the events don't get recorded anymore. Kept getting an error that the custom dimension was expecting a string but was getting a boolean ... but the code was copied exact with my id and dimension 1 ... the mystery continues (i switched back to the gtag for now bc at least i get the adblock event recorded even though I can't tell if it's true or false :p